# How can I get the names of all namespaces containing the word "nginx" and store those names in an array

Tags: arrays, bash, kubernetes, kubernetes-namespace

Basically I want to automate this task where I have some namespaces in Kubernetes I need to delete and others that I want to leave alone. These namespaces contain the word nginx. So I was thinking in order to do that I could get the output of **get namespace** using some regex and store those namespaces in an array, then iterate through that array deleting them one by one.

```
array=($(kubectl get ns | jq -r 'keys[]'))
declare -p array
for n in {array};
do
    kubectl delete $n
done
```

I tried doing something like this but this is very basic and doesn't even have the regex. But I just left it here as an example to show what I'm trying to achieve. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl get ns` doesn't output JSON unless you add `-o json`. This:

```
array=($(kubectl get ns | jq -r 'keys[]'))
```

Should result in an error like:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 5
```

---

`kubectl get ns -o json` emits a JSON response that contains a list of `Namespace` resources in the `items` key. You need to get the `metadata.name` attribute from each item, so:

```
kubectl get ns -o json | jq -r  '.items[].metadata.name'
```

---

You only want namespaces that contain the word "nginx". We could filter the above list with `grep`, or we could add that condition to our `jq` expression:

```
kubectl get ns -o json | jq -r  '.items[]|select(.metadata.name|test("nginx"))|.metadata.name'
```

This will output your desired namespaces. At this point, there's no reason to store this in array and use a `for` loop; you can just pipe the output to `xargs`:

```
kubectl get ns -o json |
jq -r  '.items[]|select(.metadata.name|test("nginx"))|.metadata.name' |
xargs kubectl delete ns
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl get ns
```

**output**

```
NAME                          STATUS        AGE
default                       Active        75d
kube-public                   Active        75d
kube-system                   Active        75d
oci-service-operator-system   Active        31d
olm                           Active        31d
```

**command**

```
kubectl get ns --no-headers |  awk '{if ($1 ~ "de") print $1}'
```

**Output**

```
default
kube-node-lease
```

this will give you a list of namespaces

```
array=$(kubectl get ns --no-headers |  awk '{if ($1 ~ "de") print $1}')
```

**Testing**

```
bash-4.2$ array=$(kubectl get ns --no-headers |  awk '{if ($1 ~ "de") print $1}')
bash-4.2$ echo $array
default kube-node-lease
bash-4.2$ for n in $array; do echo $n; done
default
kube-node-lease
bash-4.2$
```